# Python: Modify pickled objects

Tags: python, pickle

I am using cPickle to store objects. Later I would like to modify individual records. Unfortunately the file is getting corrupted after modification (I am getting UnpicklingError):

## create and Pickle

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, title, author, ISBN, price):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.ISBN = ISBN
        self.price = price

def main():
    from cPickle import dump
    from random import choice
    from random import randrange
    letters = ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k",
           "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v",
           "w", "x", "y", "z")
    f = open("books.dat", "a+b")

    for ctr in range(0, 20):
        title = ""
        author = ""
        ISBN = ""
        price = randrange(20,100)
        for i in range(10):
            title+=choice(letters)
            author+=choice(letters)
            ISBN+=str(randrange(0,14))
        book = Book(title, author, ISBN, price)
        # writing structure
        dump(book, f)
    f.close()
    print "Finished."

main()
```

## unPickle and modify

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, title, author, ISBN, price):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.ISBN = ISBN
        self.price = price

    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.title+" by "+self.author+".\n"
        rep += "ISBN: "+self.ISBN+"\n"
        rep += "Price: "+str(self.price)
        return rep

def main():
    from cPickle import load
    from cPickle import dump
    import sys

    books = []
    EOF = False
    f = open("books.dat", "r+b")
    print "Loading..."
    while not EOF:
        try:
            book = load(f)
        except(EOFError):
            EOF = True
        else:
            books.append(book)
    print "Load complete."
    rec = int(raw_input("Record to delete: "))
    print books[rec]
    fwd = 0
    for i in range(rec):
        fwd+= sys.getsizeof(books[i]) 
    print str(fwd)
    title = "New"
    author = "New"
    ISBN = "New"
    price = 0
    new = Book(title, author, ISBN, price)
    print str(sys.getsizeof(new))
    f.seek(fwd)
    dump(new, f)
    f.close()

main()
```

Comment: What's the exact error? Anyway, you might try using the now built-in sqlite3 module. That will also provide an easier migration path to a real database should you ever have to do that.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aed0101/Dropbox/QSAP/cPickle/unpack.py", line 49, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/aed0101/Dropbox/QSAP/cPickle/unpack.py", line 27, in main
    book = load(f)
UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '_'.

Comment: I have tried sqlite3. Will be using it. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but it seems to me that since you already have a list of books objects(loaded from file) so it will be easier and error free for you if you will rewrite your file with the context of this list(you can remove record you want or simply books[i]=new) using dump instead of trying to finding a plave where to insert your new record.

In other words try the following:

```
class Book(object):

    def __init__(self, title, author, ISBN, price):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.ISBN = ISBN
        self.price = price

    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.title+" by "+self.author+".\n"
        rep += "ISBN: "+self.ISBN+"\n"
        rep += "Price: "+str(self.price)
        return rep

def main():
    from cPickle import load, dump

    print "Loading..."
    books = [load(line) for line in open("books.dat", "rb")]
    print "Load complete."

    rec = int(raw_input("Record to delete: "))        
    title = "New"
    author = "New"
    ISBN = "New"
    price = 0

    books[rec] = Book(title, author, ISBN, price) # replace previous record

    with open("books.dat", "wb") as f:        
        for record in books:
            dump(record, f)


main()
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to do it without overwriting. It seems like getsizeof is not reporting the correct size.

Comment: @aeed0101 - not sure that using seek, getsizeof and so on will give you benefit in this case.